# PIG - Hbase - RowKeyDistributorByHashPrefix - DistributedScanner

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

We are using `RowKeyDistributorByHashPrefix` to avoid region hotspots.  Can I still  use the -lte & -gte options on HbaseStorage to limit the scan?  My gut feel is that I can't...I have a feeling that HbaseStorage doesn't use DistributedScanner.

Answer (score 0):

HBaseStorage does not support it. However, since it is open source. You can take [the code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.java) modify it and then use your custom Storage function instead